# How to express multi condition rules with flow diagram or truth table

Tags: gui-design, accessibility, workflow, wireframe, prototype

I have a below mentioned multiple variable which match with the other variables and gives output like `FALSE`, `HOLD` or `TRUE`.

I have tried to represent it here in table format.

```
   Variable            Condition
Var1   Var2     Con1    Con2    Con3   Con4     Con5
A      A1       Hold    True    True   False    Hold
A      E1       Hold    True    True   False    Hold
A      D1       Hold    True    True   False    Hold
D      A1       Hold    True    True   False    Hold
D      E1       Hold    True    True   False    Hold
E      A1       Hold    True    True   False    Hold
E      D1       True    True    True   False    Hold
D      A1       True    True    True   True     Hold
```

How should I present the above mentioned structure in flow diagram or in simple English language by writing it on technical requirement document.

The purpose is to make the development team to understand that each condition should be check in a sequence from `FALSE`, `HOLD` & `TRUE` (i.e. If any condition match with `FALSE` then break the loop and mark it as a `FALSE` else check `HOLD` condition and last `TRUE`).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should provide that data in a flow diagram. A Decision Table [1] (quite like the one you provided in the Question) is the typical way to convey such information to engineers and the typical way for engineers to consume such data. You may be able to simplify the Decision Table [2] (ask the engineers/developers to help with that).

It would be useful to also provide a written explanation in simple English as long as it doesn't invite ambiguity. Having a solid grasp of English and technical writing would be desirable skills if embarking upon that task.

[1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=caCfONlau6I

[2] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHokvz4fRGY

https://www.guru99.com/decision-table-testing.html